# why linux process is lightweight than windows's?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I heard that linux process is "lightweight" than windows's process.

Linux process is more like the "thread" in windows.

So, applications such as Oracle Database is implimented by multi-process in linux and multi-thread in windows.

So, what does this "lightweight" mean?

Comment: from wikipedia: 'On Linux, user threads are implemented by allowing certain processes to share resources, which sometimes leads to these processes to be called "light weight processes"'

Comment: Because Linux and Unix have separate [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) system calls. Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By "lightweight" they mean that the cost of creating a new process on Linux is less than the cost of creating a new process on Windows. The term cost basically means the time and OS resources necessary.

Linux processes start a new process by calling [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html). This creates a new process, but doesn't duplicate the memory, and is therefore very quick. Instead the memory of the new process is flagged as [copy on write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) so that if the new process starts changing its address space then only the pages that are touched will be copied. Because of the speed of this approach applications can quickly spawn a new instance of themselves to handle incoming work. It also has the advantage over threads that if the child processes crashes it wont take down the parent process.

Windows doesn't support `fork` and the only way to start a new process is to launch a completely new copy of it. This means that even if a proces is about to start a new instance of itself the OS will have to treat the new process as a completely independent process and will not be able to make use of the pages of the the currently running process. Because of this it takes longer to start a new process than on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux threads and processes are both "tasks." There is no separation of the two in the kernel level. To create a new task you make the `clone` system call and you get to decide which of your resources you want to share with it. When a task shares the memory space of its parent you tend to call it a thread, and when it gets memory space of its own you tend to call it a process.

Therefore describing a program on Linux as multi-threaded or multi-process is a little misleading: behind the scenes they are the same. Are they more lightweight than Windows processes? You would have to write a benchmark to find out.